# What happened in the hospital at the end of the anime/manga?

Tags: monster

I don't understand where Johan went after he "mysteriously" got out of the hospital.  Dr. Tenma seems to be finally OK and I don't understand how after all this, Yohan still lived.  He was the one who caused all this evil in the first place!

A fantastic anime, but a confusing one at the end. Can someone explain what happened?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Obviously, this entire post is going to be spoilers.

> It's left as an open issue at the end of the series. Johan was operated on and saved yet again by Tenma and when he went to visit Johan at the police hospital, who was in a coma originally, Johan sat up and was talking to Tenma. But later we see the same room with an empty hospital bed.
> The conversation at the end was about which child Johan's mother wanted to keep, him or Anna/Nina. So there may be a clue in that.

Some of the possibilities:

> 1. He died after waking up from the coma and talking to Tenma (Or Alternatively, the talking to Tenma bit could have been a daydream, but he died anyways)
> 2. He was released and he's alive and well
> 3. He escaped from the police hospital just like the beginning of the show and continues his ways.

.

> But the focus should be on the mother and her choice on which twin to give up and which to "save" and the title of the last episode, "The Real Monster". There's always been confusion as to which was which because previously we were told from conflicting memories. Some people think that the title of "The Real Monster" is the mother, some people think it's referring to everyone and the world, how the world can make anyone a monster, or, Johan is the real monster afterall. Each of these sort of correlates to one of the possibilities.
> If the mother was the real monster for choosing one twin and unwanted the other, Johan dies and Nina lives. If everyone's really a monster, Johan was absolved (for the most part, maybe not criminally) of all of his crimes because the world and the people in it are the real monsters. If Johan is the true monster here, then he escaped from the police hospital and continues to play the role of the "real monster".

So it's up to your interpretation. Who do *you* think the real monster is?

Comment: Great answer, your correct there's no easy answer to who the real monster is, its up to us to decide, it really does keep us thinking, which seems to be the writers intention.

Thank again.

Comment: It was suggested in the comments on [this wiki](http://obluda.wikia.com/wiki/Johan_Liebert) that Johann finally committed suicide - jumped out of the hospital window. It's a deliberate open ending though.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Mother is the real monster but that doesn't mean Johan dies. What kind of a mom gives up a child without wanting it?

If Anna is the unwanted twin (which I think) then Johan dressed and acted like her to try to protect her. But of course the mom knows who she is and hears her voice and sends her to the Experimental Mansion. Then Johan becomes that way because of his hatred for his mother who leaves him in The Three Frogs.

If Johan is the unwanted twin then he cross-dressed like Anna because he knew he was and wanted to protect himself. That would mean his mother made a mistake to send Anna to the Mansion and Johan tries to change his past because he was supposed to go there..? Then Johan would be a monster because he knows he was unwanted and wants to change his past.

Johan probably didn't die because this isn't some Hollywood drama and it's obvious Tenma saved his life (twice). Maybe Johan left to see his mom.. or escaped in the end, because she is alive.

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing and seems to be based more on speculation than on any clear facts or evidence. Do you have any evidence to back up your claims?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that Tenma was hallucinating when he saw Johan talking to him and maybe he was thinking what Johan could say something to him if he was awake. Johan knows what his mother did and when he wakes up from the coma he escapes from the hospital.

Answer (score -1):

The tricky part that confuses everyone is the memory of the Rose Mansion because it is unknown to whom it actually belonged to. Was it Anna or Johan?, and for the Mother's case, clearly she was under so much pressure that she could had committed the mistake.

Secondly the way the twins were dressed both as girls probably suggests their mom knew this was going to happen. So for her sake and to prevent any emotional attachment while taking decision and to fool her mind or herself, she made them dress that way but there is no denying that Johan had a mindset of a psychopathic killer that he had exhibited from the times of 511 Kinderheim, however for me the real plot says the world was the monster to the twins. I support this by saying that it was the experiments that made their mindset corrupt. It's not like the twins were born with a killer mindset were they?

Secondly, about the last episode it is clear the mother is herself, however she is not sure which twin she choose to let loose, nor is Johan or Anna. It is also clearly evident that they were both blaming any one of these three as "The Real Monsters" which is foolishness. It's The situations created by Nazis and Humans that were "The Real Monsters".

A third point to consider is the empty bed at hospital and it's possible that Johan committed suicide. After all his whole plan was a "Perfect Suicide" or he could have possibly escaped and remained underground all throughout his life because he finally got a name, so he was no longer "A Nameless Monster" anymore and that is what I think happened at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Tenma is the real monster.

Inspector Lunge suspected Tenma as a suspect even after knowing everything about Johan and Tenma. He had triggered something fishy and at last he failed his conception as it's also beyond the thinking of Inspector Lunge. That is why even in second to last episode he said "Tenma is prime suspect" just before he met Tenma, he says "Sorry". I think this is a bit tricky in Inspector Lunge's conception about "Tenma".

However, Johan's Character was beyond our imagination the way he could control everyone, so is the anime,it's beyond our thinking if we don't stress on it. This is my personal conception though and will mainly be based off speculation/opinion.

I plan to watch the anime again to improve my answer and point.

Comment: Please could you edit your answer to include more substantial information on the topic. Providing links/quotes from reliable sources would help the cause. The answer as it is now, can barely be made into something more than speculation and/or personal opions.

Comment: @debal- I agree, I had tried editing the question but it really needs some work.